# Redirect 301 from asp tp wordpress on windows server 2008 IIS 7.5

Tags: php, redirect, asp-classic

I need to redirect 500 pages made in ASP to my new wordpress site.
All is on windows server 2008 IIS 7.5.
I would appreciate if someone could give me the exact code and how and where to implement it, for example: /product?id22.asp to redirect to /mansclothing.php.

- The asp pages are coming from database, therefore I cannot make it in IIS by clicking on each page, they are all in DB.

Thanks,
Yosi

Comment: This question is more suitable for ServerFault.

Comment: URL Rewrite http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: I presume you mean "/product.asp?id=22" rather than " /product?id22.asp" :)